# MySQL - PHP - Checking value of next row to close a <ul>

Tags: php, mysql, html-lists

I have a mysql table

```
|------------|-----------|------------|
|  Catagory  |    Item   |   Price    |
|------------|-----------|------------|
|    Soup    | Split Pea |  $1.99     |
|    Soup    | Onion     |  $2.99     |
| MainCourse | Steak     |  $9.99     |
| MainCourse | Shrimp    |  $11.99    |
|-------------------------------------|
```

I am looking to end up with html unordered list

```
 Soup<br>
       <ul>
            <li class="menuItem">Split Pea - $1.99</li>
            <li class="menuItem">Onion - $2.99</li>
       </ul>

  MainCourse<br>
       <ul>
            <li class="menuItem">Steak - $9.99</li>
            <li class="menuItem">Shrimp -$11.99</li>
       </ul>
```

This is my php

```
 <?php $testvalue='1' ?>
 <?php do { ?>
 <?php if ($testvalue!=$row_rs_items['category']) { echo $row_rs_items['category']; echo "<br>","<ul>"; } ?> 
  <li class="menuItem"><?php echo $row_rs_items['name']; ?> - <?php echo $row_rs_items['price']; ?></li>
  <?php $testvalue=$row_rs_items['category']; ?>    
  <?php } while ($row_rs_items = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_items)); ?>
```

The code works to create opening `<UL>` on the first entry for catagory.  However I am looking for a way to add a  `</UL>` when the next row is of a new catagory.  Is there a way to peak in to the next row when interating over the recordset?

Comment: There is absolutely no reason for jumping in and out of PHP all the time.

Comment: very true...  I was mostly doing a lot of cutting and pasting during the testing phase so seperate PHP starts and stops made sense.. but you are 100% correct once you know what you are doing I dont need to jump in and out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$row_rs_items = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_items);
if($row_as_items)
 {
  $prevCategory=$row_rs_items['category'];
  $currCategory=$prevCategory;
  echo "<ul>";
  do
   {
      if($prevCategory!=$currCategory)
       {
          echo "</ul><ul>";
          $prevCategory=$currCategory;
        }
      echo "<li class='menuItem'>$row_rs_items[name]</li>";
      $row_rs_items = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_items)
      if($row_rs_items)
          $currCategory=$row_rs_items['category'];
   }while($row_rs_items);
    echo "</ul>";
 }
```

Comment: This works perfectly and makes a lot of sense...   thank you so much..



Two tiny typos if anyone is trying to reuse this..  Line 2 - $row_rs_items...  and missing a ; near the bottom